# How to do I define CSS for a specific instance of "a"?

Tags: css, html, web

So in my CSS file, I have:

```
a {
    color:#00adef;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight:bold
}
```

But I don't want all links to be of that certain color/weight. So how would I create a specific "instance" of it, so that I could define the CSS for all  HTML tags within a specific div (say nav), but won't affect the links outside of that div?

Comment: `a#linkwithid { ... }`.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming your div has id `nav` and you want all links inside it to have these styles...

```
#nav a {
    color:#00adef;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight:bold
}
```

Alternatively, you could assign a class to specific links...

```
<a href="..." class="my-link-class">Link1</a>
<a href="..." class="my-link-class">Link2</a>
```

using this css:

```
a.my-link-class {
    color:#00adef;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight:bold
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just make the rule specific to all anchors within div#nav tag:

```
#nav a {
    color:#00adef;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight:bold
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make your "a" tag, selector, id or class specific. Like so..

```
nav a{
    color:#f00;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:20px;
}
#menu a{
color:blue;
text-decoration:underline;
font-size:16px;
}
.menu a{
color:green;
text-decoration:underline;
font-size:14px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can select particular links within a block with the basic CSS syntax and the `nav` HTML5 tag:

```
nav a {  /* every "a" tag in nav blocks */
    color:#00adef;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight:bold
}
```

You can specify which `div` if you have many with a class or an ID:

```
div#nav a {  /* every "a" tag in nav block id="nav" */
    color:#00adef;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight:bold
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Within the div id="nav" all the "a" elements  will have the same style, as you set it through CSS (like the first div you see below). You can also create a second div to manage the styling when the mouse is over the "a" element.

```
#nav a {
color:#00adef;
text-decoration: none;
font-weight:bold;}

#nav a:hover{
color:grey;
text-decoration: underline;
font-weight:bold;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#a1 {
    color:#00adef;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight:bold
}

<a href="..." >Link</a>
<a href="..." id="a1">Link1</a>
<a href="..." >Link2</a>
```